Firestore transaction retry behavior doesn't match limits
Per the firestore documentation in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas and https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#datastore-datastore-transactional-update-nodejs
"Transactions expire after 270 seconds or if idle for 60 seconds."
What is "idle" here?  The CPU?  Or does this reference the maximum time between interactions with firestore via transaction read/write?  The behavior I'm seeing here doesn't match the documents at all.
Specifically,
Using the Node.js api, when I run a transaction that takes less than 270s of total time but has long blocks of synchronous CPU activity (no IO) that take >120s total between transaction read/write operations, the transaction retries until failing.  When the time taken by the long block synchronous CPU activity is <120s, the transaction does not retry and succeeds immediately.
Specifically, any transaction like:
(transaction) {
   transaction read operation
   120s of calculating a hash or whatever
   transaction write operation
}    

<270s total time
retries until failure, whereas any transaction like:
(transaction) {
   transaction read operation
   110s of calculating a hash or whatever
   transaction write operation
}    

<270s total time
Succeeds without retrying.
What is going on?  Is the idle time limit actually 120s and calculated w.r.t. Firestore transaction interactions?

I suggest taking this up with Firebase support directly. Since the backend of the system making these decision is not open source, we unpaid volunteers of the Stack Overflow community are unlikely to be able to tell you how things actually work.  If your observations are different than the documentation, then it might just be as simple as an update the docs (which we can't do for you).

I reached out to their support team and they responded that, essentially:

IDLE is with respect to interactions with firestore via reads/writes, not CPU idle
don't have "other tasks are running alongside the transactions and preventing them from doing their job"

So basically, if you want to do an atomic read+modify+write operation on a document where the "modify" operation takes longer than 60s to run on the CPU, Firestore is going to just retry your transaction until failure.

I reached out to their support team and they responded that, essentially:

IDLE is with respect to interactions with the firestore API via reads/writes, not CPU idle
Don't have "other tasks that are running alongside the transactions and preventing them from doing their job" - which I guess means anything at all other than firestore API calls since this behavior is the same when doing a single synchronous function call between the firestore API interactions.

So basically, if you want to do an atomic read+modify+write operation on a document where the "modify" operation takes longer than 60s to run on the CPU, Firestore is going to mysteriously retry your transaction until failure.
They didn't comment on the actual limit on time between interactions varying from 60s up to around 120s depending on the number of firestore interactions in the transaction, but that is the behavior I am seeing.
Given that an atomic read+modify+write is a pretty common pattern, I'm pretty surprised by how lacking their documentation is about this behavior.  Just another Firestore footgun I guess ¯_(ツ)_/¯
